# Wave power calculations

Tags: energy

In my exam solutions we try to find the Power per unit length of the wave (which is idealized as being a rectangular block moving with a velocity v, not sinosuidal). The power per unit length is given by: $$P = \frac{1}{2}A^2\rho g v$$

Where $A$ is the average height of the wave with height $2A.$

Now the question says given a wave with $0.6$m in height, and density of seawater $1.2×10^3 \text{kg} \text{m}^{–3}.$ The answer solutions say, the velocity of the water changes from $0.5 \rightarrow 10$ ms$^{-1}$, then plug in to the above equation with $A = 0.3$m we get:
 $$P = \frac{1}{2}A^2\rho g v=\frac{1}{2} 0.3^2\times1.2×10^3 \times 10\times(0.5 \rightarrow 10)=270 \rightarrow 5400\frac{\text{W}}{\text{m}}$$

My question is where did this velocity $v$ of $0.5 \rightarrow 10$ ms$^{-1}$ come from?

Comment: Are you sure the point of the questions is not just to simply compare the values? As in the speed is changed arbitrarily and you're supposed to see the change in power? You're not giving us the question. Does it simply just say plug in the above numbers?

Comment: The question is this: The density of sea-water is $1.2×103$ kg m$^{–3}$.  Using the expression in (b)(ii), estimate the gravitational power per metre length available in a wave of height $0.60$ m. Of course the expression is deriving the power per unit length equation.

Comment: So the questions does not say anything about the change in velocity ? Where you not given the numbers somewhere?

Comment: This is exactly why I am confused it does not give  the values but in the mark scheme there is these two values of velocity.

Comment: If i received this question in an exam i'd then first calculate P=b*v where b * 1/2*A2*p*g, and then i'd just put in a few arbitrarily values for the velocity. I'd not worry about where these numbers came from, i think they're just there as examples.